# How to catch the current intent in android application

Tags: android, android-intent

I have used Intent Filter for my android application and my application is run when it receives the intent. I want to send the **received intent** to one of the method in my code that has argument of type intent. How can I make an object from the received intent (that runs my application) and send to the mentioned method in my code. Thanks a lot if anyone can help.

Comment: getIntent from your activity ?

Answer (score 1):

in `onCreate()` use

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

This returns the Intent that was sent to start the Activity.

Comment: Deprecated.  What is the method with ADS 4, Android R or later?

Comment: @Olie `Activity.getIntent()` is not deprecated. Please look again.